# Error AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028- in android studio

Tags: android

Dears;

When I’m tiring to build the APK the below error appers;
AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d9faaaf26fc140f365e3b207d6db990b\jetified-play-services-base-17.0.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon

I’ve tried
aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false

but still the same

could you please help ?